# How to use Python (preferably pandas) to scrape data from Javascript table?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, web-scraping

I am using pandas to grab some ice hockey stats from a web page as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

url_goal = 'http://www.quanthockey.com/nhl/records/nhl-players-all-time-goals-per-game-leaders.html'
df_goal = pd.read_html(url_goal, index_col=0, header=0)[0]
```

This works great, but the problem is that switching to the second page of the stats table on the homepage, does not change the url, so I cannot use the same approach to grab more than the top 50 players. There is a javascript address to the table that does change as the page number switches. I read a little about selenium and beautifulsoup, but I don't have these installed so I would prefer to do it without them is possible. So my question is two-fold:

1. Is there any way to grab data from the different pages in this
   javascript table using only pandas and standard Python/SciPy
   libraries (Anaconda to be exact)?
2. If not, how would you go about getting this data into a pandas data frame with the help of selenium or your package of choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Open the network analyzer in your browser and watch what happens when you navigate to different pages; you'll notice a `GET` request to a page like

```
http://www.quanthockey.com/scripts/AjaxPaginate.php?cat=Records&pos=Players&SS=&af=0&nat=alltime&st=reg&sort=goals-per-game&page=3&league=NHL&lang=en&rnd=451318572
```

Notice the `page` part of the query string.

You can just iterate through the range of numbers corresponding to how many pages there are, changing the query string `page` parameter, increasing it by one each time (for example)

Comment: This works great thank you! Very useful tip overall, I wasn't aware of the network analyzer. Out of curiosity, do you know the purpose of that last random string of numbers? I am not including it and it is working just fine.

Comment: Yes the network analyzer is quite useful - most of the time it can help in coming up with a strategy. Not sure what the rnd parameter is; presumably it serves some purpose or else it wouldn't be there - maybe some kind of internal record keeping.

Comment: Hi @Ryan ,      I have a link - https://www.quanthockey.com/khl/seasons/2020-21-khl-players-stats.html     , I'm able to convert to csv using pandas but I have to change the code for every year like for 2020-21 , 2019-2020 and so on. Is there any way where I can get all the available data without every time changing the year in url